# Android Notification Not getting Sound- FCM using PHP

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notification using php in my android application. Its working fine but in some device I am not getting sound during notification. Notification coming and showing but it does not play sound. I have tested three Samsung devices (6.0, 7.0) and all have same issue. In My OnePlus device sound comes.
 My PHP code is like below

```
<?php
function sendFCM($notification, $data, $token)
{
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $server_key = 'MyKEY';

    $fields = array();
    $fields['notification'] = $notification;
    $fields['data'] = $data;
    $fields['to'] = $token;

    $headers = array
    (
        'Content-Type:application/json',
        'Authorization:key=' . $server_key
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE)
        die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));

    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

and

```
sendFCM(array("title" => $row[0] . " is Online", "body" => "",'priority'=>'high'), array("message" => ""), $row[1]);
```

My Android codes is like below

```
public class FCMMessageHandler extends FirebaseMessagingService
{
    public static final int MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 6545;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        assert notification != null;
        createNotification(notification);
    }

    private void createNotification(RemoteMessage.Notification notification)
    {
        Context context = getBaseContext();

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
                .setContentText(notification.getBody());
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (mNotificationManager != null) {
            mNotificationManager.notify(MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if I am missing something.
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Plz include below code:-

```
Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
builder.setSound(alarmSound);
```

Little bit documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#setSound(android.net.Uri,%20android.media.AudioAttributes))

Previously it was handled with setDefaults(), but this method was deprecated in API level 26. So you have to use `enableVibration(boolean)`and `enableLights(boolean)` and `setSound(Uri, AudioAttributes)` instead.
Please check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setDefaults(int)) for more information on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ToneGenerator` in your `createNotification`

```
ToneGenerator toneG = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, ToneGenerator.MAX_VOLUME);
toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_HIGH_L, 3000);
```

You could also add vibration

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

((Vibrator)getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you send push notification from firebase make sure that sound option enabled
also make sure that you have added permissions in android manifest for vibrate.